# How can i store the password using sharedPreference class?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am developing a android application for fetching data using messages. for password creation here is my code, how can i store the password using sharedPreference class ?

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button Switchon;
 EditText passwd; //button name
 String ms;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    passwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwd);
    Switchon = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Switchon);



    Switchon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        String  ms = passwd.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have  successfully created and this app is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



    }
```

Comment: So ,What you have try in SharePrefrence in code ?

Comment: @akbari dipali yes, store the password when a Button clicked.. please help me.... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To store values in shared preferences:**

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("password","123456");
  editor.commit();
```

**To retrieve values from shared preferences:**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  String name = preferences.getString("password","");
```

Comment: to add to Nirav's answer, Dont' forget to hash the password. Passwords should never be saved as plain text. lee this link for an example of how to hash it. http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/

Comment: @Umoh : I know that , this is just example